# Loading custom configuration files

Tags: c#, configuration

I know I can open config files that are related to an assembly with the static `ConfigurationManager.OpenExe(exePath)` method but I just want to open a config that is not related to an assembly. Just a standard .NET config file.

Answer (score 268, accepted):

the articles posted by Ricky are very good, but unfortunately they don't answer your question.

To solve your problem you should try this piece of code:

```
ExeConfigurationFileMap configMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
configMap.ExeConfigFilename = @"d:\test\justAConfigFile.config.whateverYouLikeExtension";
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
```

If need to access a value within the config you can use the index operator:

```
config.AppSettings.Settings["test"].Value;
```

Comment: @Oliver By `whateverYouLikeExtension`, do you mean that you *must* have *something* after `config.`?

Comment: @Oliver Got around to try now, and seems to work fine without :)

Comment: @Oliver how can I write to AppSettings of this config. It raises "Cannot access protected internal indexer" now.

Comment: I did this, but when I access ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings I'm still gettting the old data.  What am I missing?

Comment: @MAW74656: You don't have to access `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings`. Instead you have to read the value from the `config` object returned from the last statement above.

Comment: So I can't "pull the rug out", have everything in my app just use the new config file?

Comment: @MAW74656: I don't understand what you exactly mean. Maybe ask a new question and elaborate explain what you like to achieve.

Comment: @Oliver Can I write system.diagnostics for WCF tracing in "justAConfigFile.config.whateverYouLikeExtension"?

Comment: I am always getting null while reading sections from my custom config.

Comment: @Shesha: Then start a new question, describe what you do and what you expect. I'm sure, you'll get an answer.

Comment: thanks, this works! Except Configuration.AppSettings.Settings is not the same collection type as ConfigurationManager.AppSettings, but it is a minor issue.

Comment: For anyone else searching on how to get the appSettings after this is done: var foo = config.AppSettings.Settings["test"].Value;

Comment: Its worth adding, if you use "ExeConfigFilename " it doesn't fail if it cannot load the config - instead it just shows some default sections with no config. It would have been nice to get an exception.... `            ExeConfigurationFileMap configMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
            configMap.ExeConfigFilename = @".\junk.xml";
            Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);`    However, if you set configMap.MachineConfigFilename = @".\junk.xml"; it does fail. Use             MachineConfigFilename...

Answer (score 8):

The config file is just an XML file, you can open it by:

```
private static XmlDocument loadConfigDocument()
{
    XmlDocument doc = null;
    try
    {
        doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(getConfigFilePath());
        return doc;
    }
    catch (System.IO.FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        throw new Exception("No configuration file found.", e);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

and later retrieving values by:

```
    // retrieve appSettings node

    XmlNode node =  doc.SelectSingleNode("//appSettings");
```

Comment: Unreachable code detected after `throw new Exception("No configuration file found.", e);`.

Comment: I'll remove the return null, it won't really be reached.

Comment: why to use XML when you have such great classes from .Net library. I wouldn't suggest using this, poor on design. What next? implement a different string class... consider this.

Comment: @OtávioDécio Can I add system.diagnostics to enable tracing in custom .config file?

Comment: @FaizanRabbani not sure about the custom tracing, but according to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025(v=vs.110).aspx you should be able to add diagnostics on the config file.

Comment: @OtávioDécio My WCF service communicates with 4 other WCF services using different custom config file for each, now I want to enable tracing only on one WCF, not all of them.

Answer (score 4):

I would use [`ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configurationmanager.openmappedexeconfiguration?view=netframework-4.8#overloads).