# What is the best approach to store configuration info in a server application? (No database)

Tags: c#, .net, configuration, configuration-files

I have a server application written in C#.

As the application running, there will be **tens of thousands of** key->value mapping generated, and this info needs to be **persisted**. For each of these mapping records, there will be **update/delete** operation.

What is the best approach to store it? No database.

Is there any performance issue with **ConfigurationManager** in such case?

How about for **thousands of records?** Is it possible to avoid using any database?

Thanks!

Comment: umm - first question would be why no database? Do you mean, you haven't got a database, or you must not use a database? If the latter, then why?

Comment: I haven't got a database for this server application.

Comment: Also, I cannot add a database for it due to whole deployment restriction.

Comment: @KeepWalking - SQL Server Compact embeds within your application - no separate install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the fact you're required to have no database by your hosting, there are still several options:

1. SQL Server Compact approach when you just place your DB files under App_Data and use ADONET to get to those as if it was a fully functional SQL server.
2. OLEDB connection to csv, dbf or any other structured file.
3. Homegrown solution - something like an IDictionary<> collection persisted manually into an XML, flat file, binary array or whatever else.

Answer (score 5):

I know you said "No database", but consider the use of [SQL Server Compact](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=17876) which provides a free, small-footprint SQL Server capability that you don't need to install - it's kind of like a grown up version of Jet.

Alternatively, you might want to see if you can find an ISAM implementation.

Comment: sql server compact is a good thing. for thens of thousands of records, please use a db instead of a flatfile

Answer (score 1):

So you can always use XML for it. Or really use ConfigurationManager files (here is some example [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx) or here [Loading custom configuration files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/505566/loading-custom-configuration-files))

Comment: ConfigurationManager is easy to use. But I am not sure if any performance issue for it to handle large data.

Comment: @KeepWalking Configuration is XML too, so I don't think there could be much difference in performance.

Comment: If you're loading up many of these values at once, this might be a reasonable approach, but you'd be better off just using a flat-file in that case. Parsing an XML document to pick out a single value if going to be far from performant.

Answer (score 1):

You may not be able to use a fully fledged database, but you could consider an embedded SQL Engine:

[SQL Compact Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/compact.aspx) or [SQLLite](http://www.sqlite.org/)

I've never used SQL CE, but SQLLite is just a single DLL.

Obviously you don't have all the features of a fully fledged database engine, but they are still pretty powerful and certainly much better than Configuration Manager for persisting data.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Steve Morgan. I recommend SQL Server Compact.