# Connection String runtime initialization

Tags: c#, configuration, runtime

How do I initialize a connection string from a remote file inside my Console Application in C# :

I am currently doing this for AppSettings to load from a remote location:

string runtimeAppSettingsconfigfile = "c:\Somepath\StaticAppSettings.config"

```
System.Configuration.Configuration config
    = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
config.AppSettings.File = runtimeAppSettingsconfigfile;
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
```

How do I achieve the same for Connection strings config file i.e. load the connection string file remotely ?

EDIT :

What I have tried so far is :

```
string runtimeConnectionStringConfigfile = "c:\somepath\StaticConnectionStrings.config"
Configuration config =                          ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(runtimeConnectionStringConfigfile);

config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings");
```

Connectionstring file sample:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="mydb" connectionString="Data Source=PrimaryDB;Initial Catalog=test;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=testuser;Password=test; Asynchronous Processing=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: What do you want to load from? Sounds like it's something other than app.config.

Comment: can you post a sample of you Connection Strings file? if it's the same from where you read appSettings have you tried putting ConnectionStrings where you have appSettings in your sample?

Comment: @537mfb I tried that, but if you check the code it specifically says : config.AppSettings.File - and If I use it again it just overrides the previous section i.e. my appsettings.config file with my connectionstrings.config file

Comment: @GalacticCowboy Updated question, please check the question again.Thanks!

Comment: @MurtazaMandvi - Course it gets overriden - you're calling config.save on both. Have you tried Oliver's answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/505566/loading-custom-configuration-files ?