# How to load a custom .config file with Configuration

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, configuration

I'm not sure I am going about this right, but I am trying to write a custom configuration file for an asp.NET **web** project.  I want to make it clear this is not a windows form, because half the stuff I find is only for those.  I am trying to read and write to this file to change a couple of application settings.

I wrote this huge class using [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16466/Unraveling-the-Mysteries-of-NET-2-0-Configuration) tutorial.  Here's a simplified version:

```
namespace Tedski.Configuration {
    public class TedskiSection : ConfigurationSection {

        private static ConfigurationProperty s_propName;
        private static ConfigurationPropertyCollection s_properties;

        static TedskiSection() {
            s_propName = new ConfigurationProperty(
                "name", 
                typeof(string), 
                null, 
                ConfigurationPropertyOptions.IsRequired
            );
            s_properties = new ConfigurationPropertyCollection();
            s_properties.Add(s_propName);
        }

        protected override ConfigurationPropertyCollection Properties {
            get { return s_properties; }
        }

        [ConfigurationProperty("name")]
        public string Name {
            get {
                return (string)base[s_propName];
            }
            set {
                base[s_propName] = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am now not sure where to define my configuration.  I can put this in my Web.config file like this:

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="Tedski" type="Tedski.Configuration.TedskiSection" />
    </configSections>
    <Tedski name="Ted" />
</configuration>
```

and everything loads up fine with this:

```
TedskiSection section = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("Tedski") as TedskiSection;
Console.WriteLine(section.Name); //produces "Ted"
```

However, I need to be able to load this up with the `Configuration` object, in order to be able to call `Configuration.Save()`.  I can't seem to load up that specific section and save the Web.config (from what I understand this is dangerous).  Another solution I'm trying out is creating a separate .config file (Tedski.config) with the same XML syntax as defined above.

I tried using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/505566/loading-custom-configuration-files) answer to load up Tedski.config, but I get an error:

```
ExeConfigurationFileMap configMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
configMap.ExeConfigFilename = Server.MapPath("~/Tedski.config");
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configMap, ConfigUserLevel.None);
TedskiSection section = config.GetSection("Tedski") as TedskiSection; //fails
```

> ConfigurationErrorsException "An error occurred creating the
>   configuration section handler for Tedski: Could not load type
>   'Tedski.Configuration.TedskiSection' from assembly
>   'System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

If I got this to load, I could then modify `section.Name` and call `config.Save()`, but I'm stuck here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `type` property, you have to tell it which assembly contains your `Tedski.Configuration.TedskiSection`. For example:

```
<section name="Tedski" type="Tedski.Configuration.TedskiSection, TedskiAssemblyName" />
```

Replace "TedskiAssemblyName" there with the name of the assembly that contains the class.

Comment: That was it... I just figured it out and checked back here.  Thanks so much!