# Access web.config settings from external program

Tags: c#, web-config

I have an application residing in a virtual directory. It has the following setting in its `Web.config`:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="SomePath" value="C:\Somepath\whatever"/>
    ........other settings.........
</appSettings>
```

I have an executable that runs externally to the app that needs to read this value:

```
System.Configuration.Configuration config =  
     WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("/MyApplicationVirtualDirectory") 
     as System.Configuration.Configuration;
string path = config.AppSettings.Settings["SomePath"].Value;
```

This throws a compilation error:

> 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationElement.this[System.Configuration.ConfigurationProperty]' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Which I guess makes sense because web.configs in virtual directories contain some sensitive info like connection strings, etc but I wanted to check and make sure that I'm not doing anything wrong and that my understanding is correct. If not, how can I access this setting from my external executable?

Comment: I've used the answer of this question many times before without problems: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21171894/reading-external-configuration-file Maybe you should look into another way to share configuration though.

Answer (score 1):

This is sort of a round-abound way of solving the problem, but its the way I've done it in the past.  You can simply make a page in your Web Application that gives the setting you want back, and then use an HttpWebRequest to access that page in your executable.

Otherwise its a permission issue.  You can mess with the permissions on the Web.config file or try running the executable as Administrator.

Comment: Hmph. Now I don't get the inaccessibility error but a null ref. `AppSettings.Settings["SomePath"]` comes back null

Comment: Tried to do some more digging.  I think the first solution I described is the best option.