# Deduplicate settings

Tags: c#, configurationmanager

In a directory, I have multiple EXE files which are .NET applications. All these applications link a certain DLL, which reads data from `ConfigurationManager`. For a successful setup, the config entries have to be the same across all EXE files, but the config files are named differently: `x.exe` requires `x.exe.config` and `y.exe` requires `y.exe.config`.

So for now, I duplicate the file content, because the installer does not support hard links.

Is there a possibility to deduplicate the settings, by having every EXE's `ConfigurationManager` object point to the same configuration file, or by having parts of the configuration tree only linked into every config file from one central location?

Comment: It sounds like you want a config file version of DLL hell.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loading custom configuration files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/505566/loading-custom-configuration-files)

Comment: You could use MkLink to create hard links that can have different names: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/