# C#- How to use OpenFileDialog to load a ConfigurationUserLevel file?

Tags: c#, openfiledialog

I want to be able to load a config file (.config) of type System.Configuration.ConfigurationUserLevel using OpenFileDialog.

I need the file to be a ConfigurationUserLevel because the I need to use .AppSettings, as its functionality already exists in many other places throughout my code.

Currently I have,

```
if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    var extension = Path.GetExtension(openFileDialog1.FileName);
    if(extension.Equals(".config"))
    {
        try
        {
            var configFile = (ConfigurationUserLevel)openFileDialog1.OpenFile();
            var settings = configFile.AppSettings.Settings;
```

but I get an error saying that I cannot simply convert from a Stream to ConfigurationUserLevel.

Is there a way for me to get a ConfigurationUserLevel file from an openFileDialog? Or is there a workaround?

Comment: Maybe this helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/506637/572332 And to get the path and filename from the dialog try openFileDialog1.FileName (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filename(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @robor78 This worked, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`OpenFileDialog` just helps users to get `FileName`, of course you can't open file directly with `openFiledialog.OpenFile()`.

You need to read file with `FileName` from `OpenFileDialog`, and parse it then cast to `ConfigurationUserLevel`.

This can be help: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file(v=vs.110).aspx