# app.config inside Visual Studio Extension?

Tags: visual-studio-extensions, vsix

I have created a Visual Studio extension representing a Visual Studio Project wizard (vsix package).  I am attempting to wire up log4net, and this has been unsuccessful.  I have chased the issue down to my app.config not being loaded properly.

I have added this to my app.config in my visual studio extension:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="test" value="hello world"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

and within my IWizard implementation, I have added this line of code:

```
var test = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["test"];
```

However, the `test` variable above is always null when debugging.

I have verified these things:

- App.config is set to Build Action: Content
- App.config is set to Copy to Output Directory: Copy Always
- App.config is set to Include in VSIX: True
- App.config file is present in my `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_...\Extensions\<Name>\<Company>\1.0` folder

What am I missing?  And if App.config is not allowed within VSIX extension development, how would you go about wiring up log4net?

Comment: Please check if [this document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/505566/loading-custom-configuration-files) could help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What am I missing? And if App.config is not allowed within VSIX
>   extension development, how would you go about wiring up log4net?

*An App.Config file is copied and renamed during build to .exe.config, so only executables can have and use "App.Config" files using ConfigurationManager directly.
Usually,a VSIX project generates a DLL that is loaded in the Visual Studio executable (devenv.exe), so your project, using ConfigurationManager directly, can only read settings from the devenv.exe.config (folder C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 16.0\Common7\IDE).*

And when l test it with my only `app.config` file in a vsix project,the project seems to be unable to get the value of my custom files only from the default `devenv.exe.config` which contains only two values `TestProjectRetargetTo35Allowed` and `EnableWindowsFormsHighDpiAutoResizing`.This means that in any case, it gets values from devenv.exe.config.

**Solution**

1#. you can just define the new key in the `devenv.exe.config` file and you can get it directly from the file.

```
 <appSettings>
    <add key ="TestProjectRetargetTo35Allowed" value ="true"/>
    <add key ="EnableWindowsFormsHighDpiAutoResizing" value ="true"/>
      insert new key here
  </appSettings>
```

2#. You can get this app.config by code and get the values of the keys directly from it.

```
ExeConfigurationFileMap configMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
configMap.ExeConfigFilename = @"xxxxxxxx"; // the path of the custom app.config
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
var test = config.AppSettings.Settings["test"].Value;
```

**In addition**, I recommend **solution2** is better and easier to solve your issue.
Hope it could help you.

Comment: Although I am not happy with the answer (as I will have to somehow inject the configuration to other libraries) - this is the correct one.

Comment: var appConfigPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Package.GetType().Assembly.Location);
// add in your app config whatever it's name
var fullyQualifiedAppConfig = System.IO.Path.Combine(configPath, "App.config");