# VSXI referenced assemblies not loaded properly

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

In my given VSIX I have referenced .netstandard's version of nuget package  [Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client/) to get a list of [Projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/projects/about-projects?view=azure-devops) utilizing [`GetProjects()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.teamfoundation.core.webapi.projecthttpclient.getprojects?view=azure-devops-dotnet) method of `ProjectHttpClient` class from `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Core.WebApi.dll` assemly.
I get `Method not found` exception in runtime at the moment of method call.
It took me a long time to learn that, this is because a VSIX is loaded into devenv.exe App Domain which has already loaded the same referenced assembly with a different version (and different signature of `GetProjects()` method) from the following path:
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer`.

Some of things that I have done to make it work:

1. Manually appending nuegt assembly using `Assembly.LoadFrom` to the list of loaded assemblies during VSIX's `InitializeAsync` method which didn't help.
2. Trying to point runtime to use that nuget version, using [`assemblyIdentity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/assemblyidentity-element-for-runtime), which turned out to be pointless since it is apparently gets ignored in VSIX packages.[(link)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59263045/711861).
3. Replace `PackageReference` with Assembly `Reference` pointing to that version of assembly, located in the aforementioned `Team Explorer` folder which solve the problem, but it makes my VSIX tightly bound to the target environment binary versions. which doesn't sounds a logical decision.

Comment: Create a console app, zip it and include with your extension

Comment: Could you provide a sample code that reproduces the problem? Please hide sensitive information and provide a shared link.

Comment: @DevPreSupport_MSFT, you can find a sample repo that I just created [here](https://github.com/Mostafa-Armandi/ListProjects). Please see ListAllProjects command.

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce this issue on my local environment. Here is the detailed information:
[image]

we can find there are 6 parameters in the function “GetProjects”. The type of last parameter is Boolean. I can also find the related method on the class "ProjectHttpClient"

```
    public virtual Task<IPagedList<TeamProjectReference>> GetProjects(ProjectState? stateFilter, int? top, int? skip, object userState, string continuationToken)
    {
        return GetProjects(stateFilter, top, skip, userState, continuationToken, null);
    }

   
    public virtual Task<IPagedList<TeamProjectReference>> GetProjects(ProjectState? stateFilter = null, int? top = null, int? skip = null, object userState = null, string continuationToken = null, **bool? getDefaultTeamImageUrl = null**)
    {
        List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> queryParams = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
        QueryParamHelper.AddNonNullParam(queryParams, "stateFilter", stateFilter);
        QueryParamHelper.AddNonNullParam(queryParams, "$top", top);
        QueryParamHelper.AddNonNullParam(queryParams, "$skip", skip);
        QueryParamHelper.AddNonNullParam(queryParams, "continuationToken", continuationToken);
        QueryParamHelper.AddNonNullParam(queryParams, "getDefaultTeamImageUrl", getDefaultTeamImageUrl);
        return GetProjectsAsync(queryParams, userState);
    }
```

However we cannot found the GetProjects method with 6 parameters in the official site:
[image]

So I would suggest you change GetProjects method with 5 parameters:

```
 var test = projectClient.GetProjects(null,3,1,null,null).Result;
```

This is the test result:

[image]

Comment: Actually I have already done the same as what you have suggested. However, I will never be able to use that overload with 6 parameters. This is because, in run time, the actual referenced assembly from Nuget package is not loaded in the AppDomain since, another version (residing in the local Team Explorer folder) has already been loaded which lacks that overload with 6 parameters.

Comment: Yes, you are right. However it determined by build system. Currently I think the workaround will be: 1) upgrade the webapi.core under Team explorer 2) specify the parameters as I mentioned in this reply.